# The definite articles before names of people and their professions

Tags: articles

I have observed that sometimes there are professions before names of people then "the" is omitted or used. For example:

> The teacher Mark Henry will tell us more.
>
> Psychologist David Cook will see tomorrow.

So,  is it correct to use "the" before such structures, or both are correct?

Comment: With professions it is more usual to omit the article in such constructions. Teacher Mark Henry will now address the conference. Fire Officer Chris Hughes will now talk about his involvement with tower-block fires.

Answer (score 1):

Using "the" would be somewhat odd.

In a sentence like "The teacher, Mark, will tell us more", it is understood that there is only one teacher. It could be possible (for example if a police office, social worker and teacher were in a meeting), but it would be rare. (I've adjusted your grammar to *will tell* and added punctuation, based on what I think you mean)

Using "a" is possible:

In the sentence "A teacher, Mark, will tell us more." The name of the teacher is additional information, it implies that the main fact is that a *teacher* will tell us something. The name of the teacher is secondary. On the other hand "Mark, a teacher, will tell us more" introduces Mark, who will tell us something. That Mark is a teacher is additional information. In either case a relative clause could be used instead "Mark, who is a teacher, will tell us more"

Use of professions as titles, without any article, varies between dialects of English. It is less common in British English. I would not normally say "Teacher Mark"

Use of "Prime Minister" as a title is considered an error by many British speakers. It is a common Americanism to say "Prime Minister May", British speakers will more often say "The Prime Minister". Some job words can always be used as titles, for example: President, Professor, Officer, Doctor.

Comment: I have found some information about the thing. It is called "restrictive appositive." As it says it would be correct to say  "The teacher Mark Black will tell us more" becouse there is lots of teachers, but Mark Black, who is a teacher, is one, so the teacher Mark Black will tell us more. Maybe I understand the rule wrong. Could you correct me if I do?